# Implicit conversion from Boolean? to Boolean

Tags: vb.net, boolean, nullable, implicit-conversion

I'm getting a few Implicit Conversion warnings and I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong. I think I'm having a mental block.

An example of where I am seeing the implicit conversion from `Boolean?` to `Boolean` is as follows:

```
If Not calId Is Nothing Then
   Dim calendar As Model.Calendar = db.Calendars.First(Function(x) calId = x.id)
End If
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use `callId.Value` ?

Comment: Are we to assume `calId` is a Nullable?

Answer (score 3):

Use `callId.Value`. If `callId` is `Integer?`, then `callId.Value` is `Integer`. Because `callId` is nullable, the expression `callId = x.id` becomes a nullable `Boolean`, i.e. `Boolean?`. Since you need a non-nullable `Boolean` expression, write

```
Dim calendar As Model.Calendar = db.Calendars.First(Function(x) calId.Value = x.id)
```

Note that the null test can also be written as

```
If calId.HasValue Then
```

The reason for this behavoir is that `Nothing = x.id` yields `Nothing`, not `False`.

---

Note also that `calender` is limited to the scope of the `Then`-block. If you need to use it after the `If-statement`, place the `Dim`-statement before `If`

```
Dim calendar As Model.Calendar = Nothing
If calId.HasValue Then
    calendar = db.Calendars.First(Function(x) calId.Value = x.id)
End If
Console.WriteLine(calender?.Date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's sorted it :)

Comment: Or alternatively use `GetValueOrDefault()`, depending on what behavior you want in the event that `callId` is `Nothing`.  The code in the answer above will throw an exception, `GetValueOrDefault()` will substitute the default value for the non-nullable type.

Comment: The code above uses the [Null-conditional Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) `calender?.Date`.

Comment: N.B. Null-conditional Operator is only a thing in C# (not vb) @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Comment: @egmfrs, [?. and ?() null-conditional operators (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) were introduced in Visual Basic 14 (Visual Studio 2015). See [What's new for Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/whats-new/) for the new features introduced in each version of Visual Basic.